# How to assure the correct text-content rendering into certain list items' ::before pseudo-elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, rendering, pseudo-element, custom-data-attribute

I want to add an active class to every first element of the submenu (not to all the li's, only the first one from a bunch of li's with same first letter). and add the labels as A, B, C ----- i am achieving this with the css, but the problem is that it keeps adding labels to all, as i want the label to only first element. for example Brittle, britiana, bronze - it will add active class to first B only and same with the others.

how would i go about this?

```css
.groupmenu-drop {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  column-count: 4;
  counter-reset: alphabeticList;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .groupmenu-drop {
    column-count: 1;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .groupmenu-drop {
    column-count: 2;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 14px !important;
  counter-increment: alphabeticList;
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 a {
  font: 600 14px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #166665;
}
.groupmenu-drop .level1:before {
  content: counter(alphabeticList, upper-alpha);
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -40px;
  border: 2px solid #166665;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font: bold 21px/34px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #095352;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 23px;
}
.groupmenu-drop .level1:first-child:before {
  background-color: #166665;
  color: #fef6eb;
}
```

```html
<ul class="groupmenu-drop slidedown">
  <li class="level1 nav-1 item first">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/angelcare.html"
      ><span>Angelcare</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-2 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/baby-art.html"
      ><span>Baby Art</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-3 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/barbie.html"
      ><span>Barbie</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-4 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/bibado.html"
      ><span>Bibado</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-5 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/boon.html"
      ><span>Boon</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-6 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/braun.html"
      ><span>Braun</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-7 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/diono.html"
      ><span>Diono</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-8 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/disney.html"
      ><span>Disney</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-9 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dorel.html"
      ><span>Dorel</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-10 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dr-brown-s.html"
      ><span>Dr Brown's</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-11 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dreambaby.html"
      ><span>Dreambaby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-12 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dreamgenii.html"
      ><span>Dreamgenii</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-13 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dumbo.html"
      ><span>Dumbo</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-14 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/earth-friendly-baby.html"
      ><span>Earth Friendly Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-15 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/east-coast.html"
      ><span>East Coast</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-16 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/fisher-price.html"
      ><span>Fisher-Price</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-17 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/fisher-price-little-people.html"
      ><span>Fisher-Price Little People</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-18 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/flair.html"
      ><span>Flair</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-19 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/gift-wrap-accessories.html"
      ><span>Gift Wrap Accessories</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-20 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/halilit.html"
      ><span>Halilit</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-21 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/hey-clay.html"
      ><span>Hey Clay</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-22 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/hot-wheels.html"
      ><span>Hot Wheels</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-23 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/infantino.html"
      ><span>Infantino</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-24 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/janod.html"
      ><span>Janod</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-25 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/kaloo.html"
      ><span>Kaloo</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-26 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/keel-toys.html"
      ><span>Keel Toys</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-27 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lalaboom.html"
      ><span>Lalaboom</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-28 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lamaze.html"
      ><span>Lamaze</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-29 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lansinoh.html"
      ><span>Lansinoh</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-30 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/leap-frog.html"
      ><span>Leap Frog</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-31 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lindam.html"
      ><span>Lindam</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-32 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/little-bird-told-me.html"
      ><span>Little Bird Told Me</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-33 item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/mam.html"
      ><span>MAM</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-34 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/mattel.html"
      ><span>Mattel</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-35 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/medela.html"
      ><span>Medela</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-36 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/mega-bloks.html"
      ><span>Mega Bloks</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-37 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/milton.html"
      ><span>Milton</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-38 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/munchkin.html"
      ><span>Munchkin</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-39 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/my-garden-baby.html"
      ><span>My Garden Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-40 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/nuby.html"
      ><span>Nuby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-41 item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/nuk.html"
      ><span>NUK</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-42 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/philips-avent.html"
      ><span>Philips Avent</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-43 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/plasticine.html"
      ><span>Plasticine</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-44 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/playmobil.html"
      ><span>Playmobil</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-45 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/ragtales.html"
      ><span>Ragtales</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-46 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/safety-first.html"
      ><span>Safety First</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-47 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/schleich.html"
      ><span>Schleich</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-48 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/summer-infant.html"
      ><span>Summer Infant</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-49 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/swaddleme.html"
      ><span>SwaddleMe</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-50 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/taf-toys.html"
      ><span>Taf Toys</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-51 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/thomas-and-friends.html"
      ><span>Thomas and Friends</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-52 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tiny-love.html"
      ><span>Tiny Love</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-53 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tommee-tippee.html"
      ><span>Tommee Tippee</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-54 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tomy.html"
      ><span>Tomy</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-55 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vicks.html"
      ><span>Vicks</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-56 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vital-baby.html"
      ><span>Vital Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-57 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vtech.html"
      ><span>vTech</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-58 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/we-made-me.html"
      ><span>We Made Me</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-59 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/widdop-bingham.html"
      ><span>Widdop Bingham</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-60 item last">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/winnie-the-pooh.html"
      ><span>Winnie The Pooh</span></a
    >
  </li>
</ul>
```

Output i am getting: https://paste.pics/be37c962a84545356f416db149368a92

i want to achieve like the screen shot below: https://paste.pics/ff36dd98eb6fcf126004b581ac466f93

Comment: i want to achieve like the screen shot here: https://paste.pics/a2ce5dde4764922067334395c3bf0fef

Comment: Post the JavaScript you tried using, we are not supposed to write everything for you, see [ask].

Comment: Looks like you want separate lists for each group.

Comment: i am getting this dynamically in magento 2 , all i want is to add the active class to only first li's with same first letter

Comment: The scss/sass posted by the OP targets an entirely different structure/approach than what the OP present with the question's markup. The OP actually needs an ordered list (`<ol/>`) of unordered lists (`<ul/>`) where each nested list contains just items of one and the same letter.

Comment: As for the OP's answering comment ... `i am getting this dynamically in magento 2 , all i want is to add the active class to only first li's with same first letter` ... please fix the rendering on magento's side. The task presented by the OP is nothing one actually want's to implement and maintain by JavaScript. One does not want to fix a presentational behavior of a broken/wrong/misleading markup hierarchy by additional client side logic.

Comment: I have the correct markup.https://paste.pics/b7b38fd2d0f0e68b1715d486b6e4539c , please just provide me right tips/code how i would achieve this. thank you

Comment: The markup which the OP provides as screenshot link and claims to be correct in fact is the correct presentation of nested lists. On the other hand it is not what the OP presented at first place as markup code (now a link too) which is a single flat list. Third the former does not match the OP's less-code whereas the latter does. The OP needs to provide everything the OP came up with until now as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (tip: Stack Snippet) with a better description of what the OP already did try and where the OP got stuck.

Comment: Thanks peter, i am sorry, i should have presented things like i have done the edits later on. all i want is to put the active class via javaScript, the list is already sorted.

Comment: @NaikJavaid ... The best advice still is ... Provide the markup as nested lists ... an ordered list of unordered lists where each of the latter contains a list of items  which all start with one and the same letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is straightforward.

- One queries a node list of all of a navigation/link-list's direct children ... `document.querySelectorAll('.groupmenu-drop > li')`.
- Following up one creates an [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) this node list and [`maps`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)s it into an array of mutated list-item elements which each gets assigned its text-content's first letter-character as value of an own `data-first-char`-attribute.
- Then one [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)s all items into an array of list-item elements which each start with a different letter than their directly preceding list-item.
- Finally [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) collected new first-character list-item one adds a related class-name like `new-first-char`.
- In the same time one would slightly change some selector rules

  - The [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) rendering would be covered by a changed rule like ...

    ```css
    .groupmenu-drop .level1.new-first-char::before {
       content: attr(data-first-char);
    }
    ```

    ... which targets every list-item that features a `new-first-char` class-name , and where the latter's content gets rendered by the value of this very element's `data-first-char` attribute.
  - The *active*/*selected* state of such pseudo-elements then just needs to be targeted by ...

    ```css
    .groupmenu-drop .level1.new-first-char.selected::before {
       background-color: #166665;
       color: #fef6eb;
    }
    ```

One has to at least touch the list elements where the pseudo-element rendering takes place because one can not rely anymore on the OP's original `content` rendering via the [`counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) css-[function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Functions). This is due to the OP's design of a single flat/non-nested list which by the OP's original counter-functionality forces the continuous alphabetical pseudo-element enumeration for each list item.

Therefore it is best to target the pseudo-element rendering by just a class-name like `new-first-char` where the pseudo-element's content gets rendered from this very element's `data-first-char` attribute-value.

```js
function init() {

  const newFirstCharacterItems = Array
    .from(
      document
        .querySelectorAll('.groupmenu-drop > li')
    )
    .map(elmNode => {

      const textContent = elmNode
        .querySelector('a > span')
        ?.textContent ?? '';

      let char = textContent
        .trim()
        // https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category
        .match(/\p{L}/u) // first letter character.
        ?.[0] ?? '';

      char = char
        .toUpperCase();

      elmNode
        .dataset
        .firstChar = char;

      return elmNode;
    })
    .reduce(({ currentCharacter = '', result }, elmNode) => {

      const char = elmNode
        .dataset
        .firstChar;

      if (char !== '' && char !== currentCharacter) {

        currentCharacter = char;
        result
          .push(elmNode);
      }
      return { currentCharacter, result };

    }, { result: [] }).result;

    newFirstCharacterItems
      .forEach(elmNode =>
        elmNode
          .classList
          .add('new-first-char')
      );
}

init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; zoom: .7; }

.groupmenu-drop {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  column-count: 4;
  counter-reset: alphabeticList;

  /* additional fix */
  list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .groupmenu-drop {
    column-count: 1;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .groupmenu-drop {
    column-count: 2;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 14px !important;
  counter-increment: alphabeticList;
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.groupmenu-drop > .level1 a {
  font: 600 14px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #166665;
}

/* slightly changed selector */
.groupmenu-drop .level1.new-first-char::before {
  /*content: counter(alphabeticList, upper-alpha);*/

  /* changed content rendering */
  content: attr(data-first-char);

  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: -40px;
  border: 2px solid #166665;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font: bold 21px/34px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #095352;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 23px;
}
/* slightly changed selector */
.groupmenu-drop .level1.new-first-char.selected::before {
  background-color: #166665;
  color: #fef6eb;
}
```

```html
<ul class="groupmenu-drop slidedown">
  <li class="level1 nav-1 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/angelcare.html"
      ><span>Angelcare</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-2 item selected">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/baby-art.html"
      ><span>Baby Art</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-3 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/barbie.html"
      ><span>Barbie</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-4 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/bibado.html"
      ><span>Bibado</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-5 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/boon.html"
      ><span>Boon</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-6 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/braun.html"
      ><span>Braun</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-7 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/diono.html"
      ><span>Diono</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-8 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/disney.html"
      ><span>Disney</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-9 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dorel.html"
      ><span>Dorel</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-10 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dr-brown-s.html"
      ><span>Dr Brown's</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-11 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dreambaby.html"
      ><span>Dreambaby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-12 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dreamgenii.html"
      ><span>Dreamgenii</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-13 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/dumbo.html"
      ><span>Dumbo</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-14 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/earth-friendly-baby.html"
      ><span>Earth Friendly Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-15 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/east-coast.html"
      ><span>East Coast</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-16 item selected">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/fisher-price.html"
      ><span>Fisher-Price</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-17 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/fisher-price-little-people.html"
      ><span>Fisher-Price Little People</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-18 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/flair.html"
      ><span>Flair</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-19 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/gift-wrap-accessories.html"
      ><span>Gift Wrap Accessories</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-20 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/halilit.html"
      ><span>Halilit</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-21 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/hey-clay.html"
      ><span>Hey Clay</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-22 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/hot-wheels.html"
      ><span>Hot Wheels</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-23 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/infantino.html"
      ><span>Infantino</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-24 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/janod.html"
      ><span>Janod</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-25 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/kaloo.html"
      ><span>Kaloo</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-26 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/keel-toys.html"
      ><span>Keel Toys</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-27 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lalaboom.html"
      ><span>Lalaboom</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-28 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lamaze.html"
      ><span>Lamaze</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-29 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lansinoh.html"
      ><span>Lansinoh</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-30 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/leap-frog.html"
      ><span>Leap Frog</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-31 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/lindam.html"
      ><span>Lindam</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-32 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/little-bird-told-me.html"
      ><span>Little Bird Told Me</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-33 item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/mam.html"
      ><span>MAM</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-34 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/mattel.html"
      ><span>Mattel</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-35 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/medela.html"
      ><span>Medela</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-36 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/mega-bloks.html"
      ><span>Mega Bloks</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-37 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/milton.html"
      ><span>Milton</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-38 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/munchkin.html"
      ><span>Munchkin</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-39 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/my-garden-baby.html"
      ><span>My Garden Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-40 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/nuby.html"
      ><span>Nuby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-41 item">
    <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/nuk.html"
      ><span>NUK</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-42 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/philips-avent.html"
      ><span>Philips Avent</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-43 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/plasticine.html"
      ><span>Plasticine</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-44 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/playmobil.html"
      ><span>Playmobil</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-45 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/ragtales.html"
      ><span>Ragtales</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-46 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/safety-first.html"
      ><span>Safety First</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-47 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/schleich.html"
      ><span>Schleich</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-48 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/summer-infant.html"
      ><span>Summer Infant</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-49 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/swaddleme.html"
      ><span>SwaddleMe</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-50 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/taf-toys.html"
      ><span>Taf Toys</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-51 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/thomas-and-friends.html"
      ><span>Thomas and Friends</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-52 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tiny-love.html"
      ><span>Tiny Love</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-53 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tommee-tippee.html"
      ><span>Tommee Tippee</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-54 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/tomy.html"
      ><span>Tomy</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-55 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vicks.html"
      ><span>Vicks</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-56 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vital-baby.html"
      ><span>Vital Baby</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-57 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/vtech.html"
      ><span>vTech</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-58 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/we-made-me.html"
      ><span>We Made Me</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-59 item">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/widdop-bingham.html"
      ><span>Widdop Bingham</span></a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="level1 nav-60 item last">
    <a
      class="menu-link"
      href="/brands/winnie-the-pooh.html"
      ><span>Winnie The Pooh</span></a
    >
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, i will up-vote the answer. could i get the js code explannation? Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the HTML list is in the alphabet order. I will retrieve the list using the query selector method first. Then loop and compare the text inside, if the characters are different then add an `active` class to the element.

```html
<div class="elate_brands">
    <div class="groupdrop-link">
        <div class="mainbrand-item item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="#"><span>Albama</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mainbrand-item item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="#"><span>Brittle</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mainbrand-item item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="#"><span>Beat</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.mainbrain-item > .menu-link > span');

    let firstLeter = '';
    for (const element of elements) {
        if(firstLeter !== element.text[0].toLowerCase()){

            // select the parent element which is the div with mainbraind-item class
            element.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('active');
            firstLeter = element.text[0].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Updated based on the structure OP provided.
I added the .active selector in the css code

```html
     <style>
        /* ..... */

        .groupmenu-drop .level1.active:before {
            content: counter(alphabeticList, upper-alpha);
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            left: -40px;
            border: 2px solid #166665;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 7px;
            font: bold 21px/34px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            color: #095352;
            width: 27px;
            height: 27px;
            line-height: 23px;
        }

        /* ... */
    </style>


    <ul class="groupmenu-drop slidedown">
        <li class="level1 nav-1 item first">
            <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/angelcare.html"><span>Angelcare</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level1 nav-2 item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/baby-art.html"><span>Baby Art</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="level1 nav-3 item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="/brands/barbie.html"><span>Barbie</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            // code...
            let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.groupmenu-drop > .item > .menu-link > span');

            let firstLeter = '';
            for (const element of elements) {
                if (firstLeter !== element.textContent[0].toLowerCase()) {
                    let level1El = element.parentElement.parentElement;
                    level1El.classList.add('active');
                    firstLeter = element.textContent[0].toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.this is the structure : https://paste.pics/b7b38fd2d0f0e68b1715d486b6e4539c

Comment: @NaikJavaid Can you copy/paste the structure here. the structure in the image is collapsed

Comment: @NaikJavaid ... OP please stop posting links to external code sources. Everything can be provided and achieved within e.g. a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: @BaoNguyen i have updated the code , PeterSeliger, i am sorry, i didn't knew about it

Comment: @NaikJavaid I've already updated the code regarding the structure you provide